# Run a Function Stored in an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I have created an object with the ES6 documentation, and have been successful! However, when I attempt to call the functions by doing `shardHandler('help')` or such, the console shows `Promise { <pending> }` but the 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. is never called.

Below is my code. How can I call the functions from inside the object?

```
const shardHandler = async (arg) => ({
  "ids": (client, message) => {
    console.log('1')
  },
  "respawn": (client, message) => {
    console.log('2')
  },
  "kill": (client, message) => {
    console.log('3')
  },
  "restart": (client, message) => {
    console.log('4')
  },
  "help": (message) => {
    console.log('5')
  }
})[arg] || "help";
const run = async () => shardHandler('kill');
run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several problems here.

First, calling `shardHandler` returns a `Promise` because it is an `async` function. So if you want to access one of the functions you define within your object, you'll have to `await` the promise.

```js
const shardHandler = async (arg) => ({
  "kill": (client, message) => {
    console.log('3')
  },
})[arg]

const run = async () => {
  const result = await shardHandler('kill')
  result()
}

run()
```

Then I also see that you are trying to default to returning "help" if no argument was provided to `shardHandler` but the way you wrote won't work that way : you're just resolving to the actual string `"help"` and not the function. Here are ways to do it:

```
const shardHandler = async (arg) => ({
  // ...
})[arg || "help"];
```

```
const shardHandler = async (arg = "help") => ({
  // ...
})[arg];
```

Then, unless there is some specific reason you aren't showing here (which could be totally appropriate because one must simplify their problem before posting!), `shardHandler` doesn't need to be a function: just make it an object.

```
const shardHandler = {
  "ids": (client, message) => {
    console.log('1')
  },
  "respawn": (client, message) => {
    console.log('2')
  },
  "kill": (client, message) => {
    console.log('3')
  },
  "restart": (client, message) => {
    console.log('4')
  },
  "help": (message) => {
    console.log('5')
  }
}
const run = () => shardHandler['kill']()
```

And finally, the `async` keywords seem oddly placed. It's hard to know for sure without a more complete version of the code but be careful there. Calling an `async` function always returns a `Promise` which you then have to handle with `await` from within *another* `async` context, or with `.then()` to get the actual "desired" output.

Comment: Alternatively just don't use async, as there is absolutely nothing async about this code.

Comment: Yeah I was about to address that as well. I was kinda assuming that `async` was there to show that "in a complete version of the code, these functions need async".

Comment: Thanks! Yep, this isn't a complete version of the code.